# Connecting Ubuntu Server to internet

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, dhcp, ubuntu-server

I just installed Ubuntu Server, and I want to install a few updates, however I keep getting a error message. If I try to run `ping www.espn.com` every one fails, so I believe I am not connected to my network.  During the install I gave my SSID and password, but now that I have booted I am unable to connect.  `ifconfig -a` produces my network card interface as (I believe it should). What do I need to alter (or further info provide) in order to get my server to the internet?

[image]

Trying the command `dhclient -v` for either `enp1s0` or `wlp2s0` is unsuccessful. (showing output for enp1s0 below)

```
using sudo enp1s0 or wlp2s0 returns
Listening on LPDF/enp1s0/MAC
Sending on Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 internval 3 (xid=0xb5c5cc52)
```

and this continues....until you see

```
No working leases in persisted database - sleeping
```

where 255.255.255.255 is my DNS my router IP is 192.168.8.1 and my IP range set by DHCP is 192.168.8.200 - 192.168.8.300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, your server has gotten no local IP.
This can be a DHCP problem; I assume you are using a router which serves the DHCP functionality. Try running `dhclient <interface name> -v` and see if your server is able to obtain an IP address.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant see if you are successful to scan for networks. If not, you may lack the appropriate wifi drivers.

Comment: I have never installed a app from external media from terminal.  Can you provide a tut for how I could download this to a flash drive, then install  on server from the flash drive?